# Penetration testing certificate, Kali Linux certificate?

Tags: security-testing, certification, linux

ISTQB, iSQI, Agile, Scrum certificates are well known to us.

I am wondering if there is a security penetration testing certificate? (Certified Ethical Hacker is one example, but I am specifically looking for Kali Linux related certificates here)

I Googled "Kali Linux certificate" and found some interesting results. We all know take an exam on paper does not mean much, does anyone here know of any Kali Linux certificate that is closely related to real world experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, I have found this one, **Offensive Security Certified Professional**, please follow this link for more information. [OSCP certificate on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offensive_Security_Certified_Professional)

This certificate offer a certain degree of real-world experience instead of a pure paper and pen exam.